# I want to port forward my ssh connection to my docker container, where I run gitlab

Tags: linux, ssh, git, docker, public-key-encryption

I can ssh to my docker container by giving specific port number like this:

```
ssh -p 8080 git@192.168.0.94
```

This works fine, and I am getting this:

```
Welcome to GitLab, @malinda!
Connection to 192.168.0.94 closed.
```

But I want to ssh without giving a port:

```
ssh git@192.168.0.94
```

In my docker container I have mapped my ssh port(22) to my host's port (8080).

What I tried out so far by adding user accounts ssh configurations in this path `/home/git/.ssh/config`. Below is the configuration I have added:

```
Host git
  Hostname 192.168.0.94
  User git
  Port 8080
  Preferredauthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitlab
```

This doesn't work. Since I have a public key, I will be logged into host machine from my working machine. I cannot logged into my gitlab instance by executing below command:

```
ssh git@192.168.0.94
```

Comment: Shouldn't you just run `ssh git`?

Comment: i don't want to run it from my host machine. I want to run it from my client machine.

Comment: Yeah, and if your client has the `Host` configuration to connect with User `git` to the hostname 192.168.0.94, then call it as `ssh git` from the client.

Comment: client says ssh: Could not resolve hostname git: Name or service not known

Comment: what i actually need is to ssh my gitlab which server which is running on docker container where i have mapped host port  8080 to docker port 22 i want to run it ssh git@192.168.0.94 in order to commit to git

Comment: client is actually windows machine.

Comment: Then you need to configure your client to always connect to port 8080, as you have shown with your `Host` config. This has to be configured in Windows, depending on the client you are using.

Comment: how should my config should be? would you help me

Comment: Your config should be just like the one you have shown. Please first edit your question and try to make it a little bit clearer. Specifically, which software are you using to connect to the GitLab host from Windows? Check what configuration options this software provides.

Comment: i use git bash to connect

Comment: Then simply use the `.ssh/config` that you've shown.